# How to get id from dictionary where value is the same as the one I want?

Tags: python

```
    data =
{ "skusToId": [
        {
            "skus": [
                "SKU321",
                "SKU618",
                "SKU1443"
            ],
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "skus": [
                "SKU1874"
            ],
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "skus": [
                "SKU9322",
                "SKU9097",
                "SKU978" ,
                "SKU321"
            ],
            "id": 2
        }
}
```

lets say I have a list of skus, something like:

`sku_list = [SKU321, SKU1443, SKU1874]` 
I would like to know how to get the ids where I find that sku. Note that a SKU can be found in multiple ids. Like `SKU321`.

What I'm trying is: by using

```
for elem in sku_list:
   foo = [v['id'] for v in data if data['skus'] == elem][0]
   print(foo)
```

but this only returns me:

`KeyError: 'skus'`

where in fact I need something like alist of ids where I can find that SKU.

Comment: "but that does not operate as I want." **What happens** when you try it? **How is that different** from what you want?

Comment: will add more details.

Comment: Okay, so now we know there is an *error*. The next step is to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to *understand* the problem. Look at the list comprehension carefully. Where the code says `if data['skus'] == elem`, does this make sense? Is `data` one of the dicts that has a `'skus'` key, or is it the entire data structure? Second: what actually is the list that contains the dicts we want to use - is it `data`, or is there some other work we have to do in order to get that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want you output to be

**Just a check**

```
sku_list = ['SKU321', 'SKU1443', 'SKU1874']
for obj in data['skusToId']:
   print(obj , any(map(lambda e: e in obj['skus'], sku_list)) )
```

**which skus**

```
 for obj in data['skusToId']:
     print(obj['id'], [e for e in obj['skus'] if e in sku_list] )
```

```
0 ['SKU321', 'SKU1443']
1 ['SKU1874']
2 ['SKU321']
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each item in `skusToId` list. If item contains searched SKU, add it to the `ids` map or update existing record by appending id of the matched item.

```
ids = {}

for item in data['skusToId']:
  item_skus = item['skus']

  for target_sku in sku_list:
    if target_sku in item_skus:
      ids[target_sku] = ids.get(target_sku, []) + [item['id']]
```

Here key is SKU code and value is list of item ids where this code can be found. Example output:

```
{'SKU321': [0, 2], 'SKU1874': [1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
In [51]: for i in data['skusToId']:
    ...:     for sku in i['skus']:
    ...:         if sku in sku_list:
    ...:             print(f'sku: {sku}, id: {i["id"]}')
    ...: 
sku: SKU321, id: 0
sku: SKU1443, id: 0
sku: SKU1874, id: 1
sku: SKU321, id: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> KeyError: 'skus'

This means that there wasn’t a key `skus` within your object. And that is correct because when you look at your `data` object, you can see that it has a nested list at the key `skusToId` first, and only within those list elements there is a `skus` key. So a working access would be e.g. `data['skusToId'][0]['skus']` for the first element in the list.

So you want to iterate over the `data['skusToId']` list to look for a product. And you want to select a product if the SKU you’re looking for is contained within the `skus` list of that product:

```
for elem in sku_list:
    foo = [v['id'] for v in data['skusToId'] if elem in v['skus']][0]
    print(foo)
```